# tkinter: dynamically add checkboxes to grid and read values individually

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I would like to dynamically add checkboxes to a tkinter grid and then have the user check some of them and afterwards see, which checkboxes were checked.

Here's the code:

```
    top = tkinter.Tk()
    var2 = tkinter.IntVar()
    main()
    top.mainloop()

# in main
 for feat in feats:
                counter += 1

                tkinter.Checkbutton(top, text=str(merkmal) + " ist " + 

str(label), command=lambda: testResult(),
                                             variable=var2).grid(row=counter, sticky="W")

   # callback
    def testResult():
        print(var2)
```

Two problems:

a) I need a vertical and horizontal scrollbar on my grid

I have looked at other posts and seen that I need to add a canvas and then add the scrollbar to the canvas but I havent gotten it to work. Here's my attempt:

```
w = tkinter.Canvas(top)
    scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(top, orient="vertical",command=w.yview)
    scrollbar.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='ns')

    w.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    w.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')
```

and then addind the checkboxes to `w` instead of `top`. The vertical scrollbar shows, but I cant scroll.

b) When I check one of the boxes, all of them get checked. How can I make it so that each checkbox can be checked individually?

I am new to tkinter and really don't have to learn too much into it, just need this to work somehow.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

```
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(top, bg='#FFFF12', width=300, height=900, scrollregion=(0, 0, 900, 900))
hbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(top, orient="horizontal")
hbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
hbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
vbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(top, orient="vertical")
vbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvas.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="both")
```

It shows the scrollbar, the vertical scrollbar moves a bit, but the content doesnt move. When I attach everything to a frame, then the scrollbar doesnt move either.

Comment: you can't use one `IntVar` with all `Checkbutton`. Every `Checkbutton` needs own `IntVar` - you can keep them on list . Or assign every `Checkbutton` to variable and keep those variables on list - then you will no need `IntVar`.

Comment: you can find examples how to use `Canvas` to scroll `Frame`. And then you can put checkboxes in `Frame`.

Comment: @furas I got the part with the checkboxes. Could you help me with the scrollbar? See my update.

Comment: you can find complet example for `Frame` event on SO - as I remember you have to use `create_window` to add Frame to Canvas.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/1832058

Comment: aaah perfect, thats exactly what I was missing! Thanks a lot, works fine now!

Comment: your code won't run as posted -- it has indentation problems.

Comment: yeah, but thats just the formatting here